# Action of the symmetry group of a cube on opposite faces defines a surjective homomorphism from $S_{4}$ to $S_{3}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetric-groups, group-actions, group-homomorphism

> Show that the action of the symmetry group of a cube on pairs of opposite faces defines a surjective homomorphism from $S_{4}$ to $S_{3}$.

I am stuck on this problem and don't know where to begin. I found [this relevant discussion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/757532/action-of-symmetry-group-of-cube-on-pairs-of-opposite-faces), but I am not sure how it might (or might not) help with this given problem. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: The other question you link to is very close to giving you your answer. You only need to add in the fact that the symmetry group of a cube is isomorphic to $S_4$.

Comment: Albegraically, that should be the transitive action of $S_4$ by conjugation on the set of its three Sylow $2$-subgroups.